# Is "our friends" being used sarcastically here?

Tags: phrases, expressions

Generally speaking when we say "our friend" we are referring to someone who is a friend of ours.

However, I have noticed that at times these words  are used sarcastically to refer to someone who is actually not a friend but an enemy/adversary.

So with respect to the sentence below, is the term *our friend* used as a form of irony?

> Our friends the Saudis, who never persecute women, gays and other
>   religious minority groups, have somehow managed to lead the UN Human
>   Rights Council

Comment: Err... because ***sarcasm*** actually means *the use of ​remarks that ​clearly ​mean the ​opposite of what they say*. So if you use *our friend* to refer to someone who *isn't* a friend, you're probably being sarcastic.

Comment: Same question can be asked of **ANY** phrase.

Comment: Virtually every word of that sentence is sarcastic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a form of irony.

> Definition of IRONY
>
> ...
>
> 2 a :  the use of words to express something other than and especially
>   the opposite of the literal meaning
>
> [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/irony)

Irony is very common in English (and particularly so in Britain).  It is the basis of much humour but can also be used in non-humorous ways—particularly in sarcasm.

To find out more, you can search online. Here is an extended [essay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irony) from Wikipedia.

Comment: My erstwhile American colleagues would never understand when we talked about *being threatened with promotion/pay increase etc*.